# How to force a custom render?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In set this in my `routes.rb`:

```
match 'dump/:prefix' => 'TvShows#dump'
```

Then in `TvShowsController`:

```
def dump
  render :dump
end
```

Then, I added a file named `dump.xml.builder` to the `views/tv_shows` directory with this content:

```
xml.instruct!
xml.title "Test"
```

When I do `curl http://server/xml/xyz` I get this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<title>Testing</title>
```

And the rails server output is:

```
Started GET "/dump/twd" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-11-26 23:29:28 -0500
  Processing by TvShowsController#dump as */*
  Parameters: {"prefix"=>"twd"}
Rendered tv_shows/dump.xml.builder (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 40ms (Views: 40.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

The problem is when I use a web browser to get the XML; it says: `Missing template tv_shows/dump` and the rails server output is:

```
Started GET "/dump/twd" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-11-26 23:29:21 -0500
  Processing by TvShowsController#dump as HTML
  Parameters: {"prefix"=>"twd"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 5ms

ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template tv_shows/dump, application/dump with {:handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee], :formats=>[:html], :locale=>[:en, :en]}. Searched in:
  * "/xxxxxx/ruby/pppp/app/views"
):
  app/controllers/tv_shows_controller.rb:25:in `dump'

Rendered /xxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/missing_template.erb within rescues/layout (0.4ms)
```

As far as I know, I am telling Ruby to render the view using `:dump` always... so why does it try to render to HTML?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can force the xml renderer this way:

```
 def dump
   render "dump.xml"
 end
```

On the other hand if you use:

```
  def dump
    respond_to do |format|
      format.xml { render :dump }
    end
  end
```

You will have the XML returned when asking for "dump.xml" and nothing in the other cases.

Comment: I had another issue, but your answer gave me some thoughts. Thank, you.

`if request.xhr?
   render :partial => "forms/some_form.html.erb", layout: false
end`

Now I was able to force html response for xhr request.

Answer (score 1):

set the request format inside a `before_filter` to force an xml response.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :set_xml_format

  def set_xml_format
    request.format = :xml
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Rails has a capability called ['Content Negotiation'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_negotiation). You must tell Rails which format you can provide via `respond_to` method:

```
   class TestController < ApplicationController
     def test
       respond_to do |format|
         format.html 
         format.xml
       end
     end
   end
```

then rails will look for corresponding template to render the view.
`curl` must have send accept header with accepting xml so rails automaticly render and send xml.
And you can set `params[:format]` to force request specified format like `/dump/xyz.xml`. To do this, change the route to:

```
match 'dump/:prefix(.:format)' => 'TvShows#dump'
```

Comment: I do not want to respond HTML... so that's why I didn't add `respond_to`. Also, I want to return an XML regardless what extension I gave to the URL. I mean, I want `/dump/xyz` to return XML too.

Comment: Was there ever a solution found for this?